# URL Date Pull using Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, powerbi

So I'm trying to generate a streaming dataset in Power BI, so that I can have a tab in teams that constantly updates with data from my companies database. The way I pull the data is through our platform API that generates a JSON and a URL based on the query. As far as I can find, the only way to really do this is through Powershell. I want to pull out the hours and numbers fields from the JSON and then push that data to the dashboard in Power Bi, but I have absolutely no experience with any of this, so I'm completely baffled as to where to start.

Here's the powershell code I have so far, but it throws an error in regard to pulling the URL info.

```
$request = 'http://wya.works/rta_develop/xmlServlet?&command=retrieve&sql=select%20%5B%24Hours%5D%2C%20%5B%24Date%20Worked%5D%20from%20%5B%21HOURS%5D%20&attributesOnly=Date%20Worked%2C%20Hours&contentType=JSON&referer=&time=1595271424377&key=696a666d'
Invoke-WebRequest $request
$json.RECORD | % {
$hours = 0
$date = ""

$_.Field | % {
    if ($_ -match '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}\/d{4}'){
        $date = "$_"
    }
    else {
        $hours = $_
    }
}

New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property (@{
    Date = $date
    Hours = $hours
})
}

$endpoint = "https://api.powerbi.com/beta/d6cdaa23-930e-49c1-9d2a-0fbe648551b2/datasets/34eaea1e-73b6-4759-ac8b-aaae51708654/rows?noSignUpCheck=1&key=Ur9E0GDrhkp4EwJOF4bCbg7EO7aIve54urjB8M%2BHevG1%2F6pDgRJ47Fvkmx4b%2FcMowlhV18ZYyVtF9pfG%2BM1EQA%3D%3D"
$payload = @{
"Hours" =$hours
"Date Worked" =$date
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json @($paylojnjlkhad))
```

This is a snippet from the JSON file and all of the fields I need (numeric: Hours) (date: Date Worked) are labeled the same, which makes this a lot more difficult.

```
{"COUNT":"332","DISPLAY_LIST_START":"1","DISPLAY_LIST_STOP":"332","STOP":"332","RECORD":[{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["04/23/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["04/24/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["04/26/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["04/30/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/01/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["4",["05/02/2018"]]}
```

I need to use the URL instead of the actual file, because my company's platform runs on blockchain and is constantly updated.

Comment: If you want to have a payload per field pair, you will need to make an API call after `$date` and `$hours` are both set. Then repeat that process for each pair. If your payload supports an array structure, then perhaps something different can be done. You are only doing the API call after all fields have been processed, which means you only get the last pair of `$date` and `$hours` values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an API call per pair of `$date` and `$hours`, you can do the following. This will make one call per `RECORD` value.

```
$endpoint = "https://api.powerbi.com/beta/d6cdaa23-930e-49c1-9d2a-0fbe648551b2/datasets/34eaea1e-73b6-4759-ac8b-aaae51708654/rows?noSignUpCheck=1&key=Ur9E0GDrhkp4EwJOF4bCbg7EO7aIve54urjB8M%2BHevG1%2F6pDgRJ47Fvkmx4b%2FcMowlhV18ZYyVtF9pfG%2BM1EQA%3D%3D"
$json.RECORD | Foreach-Object {
    $hours = 0
    $date = ""
    $_.Field | Foreach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}'){
            $date = $_
        }
        else {
            $hours = $_
        }
    }
    $payload = @{
        "Hours" = $hours
        "Date Worked" = $date
    }
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $endpoint -Body (ConvertTo-Json $payload)
}
```

---

If you want to make one API call after creating an array of `$date` and `$hours` pairs, you can do the following. This will only make one API call.

```
$endpoint = "https://api.powerbi.com/beta/d6cdaa23-930e-49c1-9d2a-0fbe648551b2/datasets/34eaea1e-73b6-4759-ac8b-aaae51708654/rows?noSignUpCheck=1&key=Ur9E0GDrhkp4EwJOF4bCbg7EO7aIve54urjB8M%2BHevG1%2F6pDgRJ47Fvkmx4b%2FcMowlhV18ZYyVtF9pfG%2BM1EQA%3D%3D"
$payloadArray = $json.RECORD | Foreach-Object {
    $hours = 0
    $date = ""
    $_.Field | Foreach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}'){
            $date = $_
        }
        else {
            $hours = $_
        }
    }
    $payload = @{
        "Hours" = $hours
        "Date Worked" = $date
    }
    $payload
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $endpoint -Body (ConvertTo-Json $payloadArray)
```

---

**Exlanation:**

If you want to have a payload per field pair, you will need to make an API call after `$date` and `$hours` are both set. Then repeat that process for each pair. If your payload supports an array structure, then you can create a collection of those pairs.

You are only doing the API call after all fields have been processed without creating a collection, which means you only get the last pair of `$date` and `$hours` values. As you iterate through your `RECORD` items, you are overwriting `$date` and `$hours` before the API call is ever made.

Comment: Can you explain what one API call vs. multiple would do? Is one just checking the JSON one time? and multiple would check constantly?

Comment: @getALoadOfThisGuy, I took that from your code. `\d` matches any digit. `{1,2}` matches previous character between 1 and 2 times. `/` matches a literal `/`

Comment: When I run the script I don't get any error, but I don't think its building the array. Is there a way for me to log in powershell so I can see what's happening?